# running python script for multiple files from windows cmd

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to run python script from windows cmd. When I run it under linux I put

`python myscript.py filename??.txt`

it goes through files with numbers from filename01.txt to filename18.txt and it works.

I tried to run it from cmd like

`python myscript.py filename*.txt`

or

`python myscript.py filename**.txt`

but it didnt work. If I tried the script on one single file in windows cmd it works.

Do you have any clue where the problem could be? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Unix shell convert file path pattern to actual files, then pass the result to the program. (`python myscript.py`)

But in Windows cmd, this does not happen.

See [`glob.glob`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html#glob.glob) if you want get file list that match the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Those wildcards are expanded at "shell (i.e. bash) level" before running your python script.
So the problem doesn't reside in python, but in the "shell" that you are using on Windows.
Probably you cloud try PowerShell for Windows or bash via CygWin.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
FOR %X IN (filename*.txt) DO (python myscript.py %X)
```

**Edit**, you can create a .bat with this and try it.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set files=
FOR %%X IN (filename*.txt) DO set files=!files! %%X
echo %files%
python myscript.py %files%
```

Comment: this one works but the goal of my script is to plot all 18 files together and this one plots each of the files separately ... do you know why?

Comment: I added another example. this will create a list in %files% like " filename1.txt filename11.txt"

Answer (score 0):

From batch file

```
for %%f in ("filename*.txt") do python myscript.py "%%~nxf"
```

`%%f` will get a reference to each of the files. For each of them execute your script. `%%~nxf` will expand to name and extension of file.

From command line, replace `%%` with a single `%`

EDITED - I missunderstood the problem. Next try.

In windows, there is no default expansion of wildcard arguments ( see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bch7bkk.aspx)). So, to get the same result you will need a batch file. It will concatenate the list of files and pass it to your python script

```
@echo off

    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

    set "fileList="
    for %%f in ("*.txt") do set "fileList=!fileList! "%%f""

    python myscript.py !fileList!

    endlocal
```

For a more reusable code, use something as (script calls are only echoed to screen to show efect of parameters and to avoid unneeded execution, remove when it works as intended)

```
@echo off

    setlocal enableextensions

    call :glob "*.txt" true fileList
    echo python myscript.py %fileList%

    echo.

    call :glob "*.txt" false fileList
    echo python myscript.py %fileList%

    exit /b

:glob pattern useFullPath outputList
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    if /i "%~2"=="true" (set "_name=%%%%~ff") else (set "_name=%%%%~nxf")
    set "_list="
    for %%f in ("%~1") do set "_list=!_list! "%_name%""
    endlocal & if not "%~3"=="" set "%~3=%_list%"
```

Comment: this one works as well but also treats each file separately and not together as it should. It should plot 18 files into one plot instead of plotting each to its own figure

Comment: @user3041107: Updated. Sorry, i missunderstood it.

Answer (score 0):

As `falsetru` notes, on Windows the shell doesn't expand the wildcards for you, so the correct answer is `glob.glob()`. You should iterate over all the command line arguments and expand each. This works fine in Linux/UNIX too, because the expansion of an argument without any wildcards in it (which is what the shell gives you) is the unchanged filename.  So something like this, using lazy evaluation to handle a potentially large number of args:

```
from sys import argv
from glob import glob
from itertools import chain, islice

for name in chain.from_iterable(glob(name) for name in islice(argv, 1, None)):
    # do something with each file
```